# MVC ajax call how to handle error responses

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a question regarding the ajax call: here is my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Article/DeleteArticle/"+id,
    type: "GET",
    error: function (response) {

    },
    success: function (response) {

    }
});
```

And here is my controller:

```
public ActionResult DeletePicture(int id)
{
    bool success = Operations.DeleteArticle(id);
    return null;
}
```

I would like to know what shoulud i return to get inside error? And when is this error function is called basically? If error happens on server or ..?

And regarding the success how can i pass there some data?

Real life example:

Imagine i call this ajax method to delete an article, when it is deleted, so success i would like to show some success message.  If it failed so in my action i get success=false, i would like to show some other message, like : failed.

How to achieve that?

Comment: create a json object and return it from the Action. Handle in the callback accordingly

Comment: When the timeout happens or the action does not exists the error occurs. But the deletion success or deletion fail can be sucessfully handle in you success section

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can handle your Ajax calls by creating an object that represents the response:

```
public class AjaxResponse
{
        public bool Success { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then return it as follows:

```
public ActionResult DeletePicture(int id)
{
    // success failed by default
    var response = new AjaxResponse { Success = false };
    try 
    {
     bool success = Operations.DeleteArticle(id);
     response.Success = success;
     // Set a message for UI
     response.Message = success ? "Success" : "Failed";
     }
     catch
     {
      // handle exception
      // return the response with success false
      return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
     }
     return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

You could then pass the data and handle it as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Article/DeleteArticle/",
    type: "GET",
    data : { Id : id },
    dataType: 'json',
    error: function (response) {

    // Handle error from response.Success or response.Message

    },
    success: function (response) {

        // Handle error from response.Success or response.Message

    }
});
```

The handle error could simply display the message back to an HTML element or popup some kind of javascript notification.

Comment: Error will be called if your ajax calls throws as error, you could also put a try catch around your action. I will update it above to show that.

Comment: Updated for you now. :)

Comment: Great on a sinle call.  However, this is bad when chaining Deferreds as others would incorrectly fire unless you hadle each one manually.  Which would bloat your payload.

Answer (score 1):

you can use it

```
public ActionResult DeleteArticle(int id)
{
    bool success = Operations.DeleteArticle(id);       

    return Json(success, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}


$.ajax({
    url: "/Article/DeleteArticle/",
    type: "GET",
    data : { Id : id },
    dataType: 'json',
    error: function (response) {    
       if(response!=null && response.length!=0)
       {
         alert('error');
       }    
    },
    success: function (response) {  
       if(response) {
         alert('Success');
       }   
    }
});
```